# What would be the best solution performance-wise for this upvote/downvote mechanism?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization

I'm building a question and answer platform where people can upvote/downvote just like here or like Reddit.

```
$questions =
 Question::select([
 'questions.*',
 'users.name AS username'
    ])
    ->leftJoin('questions_votes', 'questions_votes.question_id', '=', 'questions.id')
    ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'questions.user_id')
    ->groupBy('questions.id')
    ->get();
```

With this query I get the total count of each question, the username of the creator and the questions data itself.

All votes are stored in `questions_votes` (columns: `id, user_id, upvote`) where `upvote` can be 1 for upvote or -1 for downvote.

What would be the best approach to get the users voting data performance-wise? Should I...

1. Add an additional subquery in my `$questions`-query to check for the `upvote` column for each question of this user? How would that subquery look like in plain MySQL?
2. Run an extra query on each iteration of each question and check every question for a data record if I as the current user have upvoted/downvoted it?

Comment: Performancewise, with the likely sizes of data sets involved, I doubt it makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the votes every time someone views a question will make it take more and more time as a question has received more votes, because it needs to scan more rows from the `question_votes` table. You should want it to take the same amount of time to view a question that is brand new, as one that has been voted on a lot.

So you could store a column `questions.score` with the current total.

When users upvote or downvote, INSERT a row vote in the `question_votes` table, so there's a record of it. This is necessary if you want to allow users to change their vote.

But also at the same time a user casts a vote, increment or decrement the `questions.score` value and UPDATE the row in the `questions` table.

Ideally, if this is done perfectly, the `questions.score` will be a sum of the upvotes and downvotes. But it's possible that due to code bugs, it won't be perfect all the time. In fact, assume that it will become slightly inaccurate. So you might need a "double-check" background task to recalculate the score sums periodically and fix the scores.

This is what Stack Overflow does, as shown here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

The `Posts` and `Comments` tables include a `Score` column, even though individual votes are stored in rows of a `Votes` table.

The advantage for performance is that you don't need to read any rows from `question_scores` table when some user simply views a question. It's likely that viewing a question happens many times more often than voting on it, so you can avoid recalculating the exact same sum value over and over, by storing the sum of votes.

---

Re your comment:

You would have to query the `question_votes` table to find out if the current user had voted on a given question. The good news is that the number of rows you need to examine to check that is at most one per question, right? So if you have the table indexed to support this query, it eliminates the need to examine many rows.

Whether you do it in a join or a second query, it's pretty lightweight because it will only do a single-row lookup.

I'll just show the SQL, since I do not use Laravel regularly.

```
SELECT q.*, (v.user_id IS NOT NULL) AS i_voted_on_it
FROM questions q
LEFT OUTER JOIN question_votes v 
 ON v.question_id = q.id AND v.user_id = ?
```

If you have an index on `question_votes(question_id, user_id)` that would make it more efficient to do that lookup.

If there is a row matching the condition, including the fixed value of user_id, then it would return a non-null result. If there is no matching row, then it would return NULL for all columns of `v` because of the outer join.

Comment: Thank you, Bill! What an honor to get this detailed answer from you! This helps me a lot. I'd love to hear your thoughts about the other issue to find out if the current user has upvoted or downvoted a question. Should I include this as a subquery in the same query or add another single query on each iteration while looping through the questions to identify if I (as an user) have upvoted/downvoted a question?